# Python setup.py with src directory

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a simple project folder which looks like this:

```
.
├── setup.py
├── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── pricing_functions.py
```

and I want to make it an installable package.

What I *want* is to have the package named `pricer` and have the actual code taken from the `src` directory (and I don't want to rename the `src` directory).

So in python I want to be able to call:

```
from pricer import pricing_functions
```

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
   
setup(
    name='pricer',
    version='0.1',
    python_requires='>=3.7, <4',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    install_requires=[
        'QuantLib',
        'matlab-tictoc',
        'more-itertools',
        'pandas>=1.4',
        'numpy>=1.14.5',
    ]
)
```

However when I install the package in virtualnv via
`python setup.py install`
I can't make the above import. But I can do
`from src import pricing_functions` - which means my package is installed but with the name of the folder.

What should I change to call it a `pricer`?

Comment: is there any reason why you do not want to rename the directory ?

Comment: it is common to keep source code in src, it keeps the folder structure clear and transparent.

Comment: how about having a subfolder within src with the desired package name. That should solve your issue. similar to the directory structure followed here. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: I think this is one of the structures that setuptools under pyproject.toml understands implicitly (https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html), so if you would consider switching out setup.py for pyproject.toml...

Comment: As DareGhost mentioned, the project directory structure is not correct for a src-layout. All the Python code (`__init__.py` and `pricer.py`) should be in a `src/pricer` directory.

Comment: Like sinoroc said, this isn't the correct structure for a src-layout. See for example [Python Packaging User Guide - src layout vs flat layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/). It should make sense why this is required, since otherwise there's zero mention anywhere of what the name of the import package is. (P.S. be careful not to confuse [_distribution_ packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) with [_import_ packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package).)

Comment: Also, do note that `setup.py` is outdated. You might want to consider migrating to `setuptools` current `pyproject.toml` interface, or switching to a more modern build system. From the makers of `setuptools`, there's [hatch](https://github.com/pypa/hatch) and [flit](https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/), or for 3rd party build systems, there's the excellent [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/).